# PostGIS: Get Disjoint Geometry

Tags: postgis, intersection, extents

I have two polygons, I want to get the area which does not intersect. I looked at st_disjoint, it returns a boolean, I need a geometry. How do I accomplish this?

Below is my code which gets the intersection area:

```
INSERT INTO result (id,geom) 
(
select id, geom
from way group by id having (
    st_intersection(ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM vertices 
    WHERE id IN( 494733,220418,183786,234791,494733)), +0.1),
    ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM vertices 
    WHERE id IN( 494733,220418,183786,234791,494733)), -0.1))
)
);
```

My Tables structure

Way Table

[image: Way Table]

Vertices Table

[image: Vertices Table]

[image]

Comment: You want to use ST_Difference http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html. If you read http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Disjoint.html the boolean result should not have surprised you `ST_Disjoint — Returns TRUE if the Geometries do not "spatially intersect" - if they do not share any space together.`

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to use the [ST_Difference](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) function. From the documentation:

> ST_Difference — Returns a geometry that represents that part of geometry A that does not intersect with geometry B.

You will need to make sure you pass in the larger polygon as the first function parameter.

---

**EDIT**

Im not 100% sure I follow your methodology; However, perhaps the following example can help point you in the right direction.

```
select
    case
    when ST_Disjoint(g1,g2) then g1 -- If geometries are disjoint, return only g1
    else ST_Difference(g1,g2) -- otherwise return g1 - the intersection of g1 and g2
    end new_geom
from(
    select
        ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM vertices WHERE id IN( 494733,220418,183786,234791,494733)), +0.1) g1,
        ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM vertices WHERE id IN( 494733,220418,183786,234791,494733)), -0.1) g2
    ) t1;
```

Comment: the function doesn't make any difference to the count of rows returned.

Comment: `code`
select count(1)
 from hh_2po_4pgr where (
  (geom_way && st_difference(ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM hh_2po_4pgr_vertices_pgr 
  WHERE id IN( 16806,276985,79770,16806)), 0.3),
  ST_expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM hh_2po_4pgr_vertices_pgr 
  WHERE id IN( 16806,276985,79770,16806)), -0.1)))
)

Comment: You will get a result for each comparison. You much check if there is any difference in the areas: if original and difference polygons have same area there were no overlaps.

Comment: Is there no way to get the entire records area difference and not on each row difference??

Comment: @KaiSocrates As user30184 has said - alternatively you can use ST_Disjoint as a check beforehand, then only using ST_Difference in the cases where ST_Disjoint is False.

Comment: Some pseudo code would be great

Comment: @KaiSocrates Can you provide a bit more information on your tables?

Comment: @Ali Basically I have a road network. I want to generate a round trip. To prevent the user travelling in the same road twice I need to abandon the center part of the bounding box...the green part is the bounding box generated.. I want to skip the red part...

Comment: Thanks for providing the extra information. Still a bit of confusion on my part but i've updated the answer to include an example which you may find useful.

Comment: @Ali.. what you are doing is returning a difference/disjoint result for every row. I want to skip the rows which are not intersecring. I'm not looking for row basis difference, I'm looking for difference as a whole